# Smooth plotting in pgfplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I currently use pgfplots to plot a function that is plotted in a very "unsmooth" and egdy manner.

```
\documentclass[]{acmart}
\usepackage[]{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            xlabel={$f$},
        ylabel={$g(f)$}, 
        xmin = 1.0,
        xmax = 4.0, 
        ymin = 0,
        ymax= 10
        ]
        \addplot[blue, very thin]{10*(1-1/(1 + (x-2)^2 ))};
        \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

And this plot is very edgy. Is there an alternative?

Comment: add more samples via `samples=101` either to plot options or to axis options apply to plots in that axis

Comment: The [smooth] key applies a quadratic spline.  See page 78 (pgfplots manual).

Comment: Regarding `smooth`, note that it may give wrong plots in some cases, so the number of samples should be considered anyway (see for example https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/371245/how-to-create-a-ricker-wavelet-in-tikz/371248#371248).