# How do I create a curve on Latex?

Tags: tikz-pgf, plot

I want to create a curve using tikz. As can be seen, the curve is made of connected lines with no rounded connection points and I would like to round off the edges. Following is my code:

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{nomencl}
\makenomenclature
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[comma]{natbib}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage[super]{nth}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\renewcommand{\sectionautorefname}{Section}
\renewcommand{\chapterautorefname}{Chapter}
\parskip=0.05in

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\label{sim}
\begin{axis}[
xlabel={Hydration time (h)},
ylabel={Hydration heat evolution rate (J/gh)},
xmin=0, xmax=100,
ymin=0, ymax=20,
legend pos=north east,
ymajorgrids=true,
grid style=dashed,
]

\addplot[
color=blue,
]
    coordinates 
{   (0,0) (0.5,3.59) (1.5,8.65) (2.5,15.026) (3.5,18.63) (4,18.07) (4.5,15.91) (6.5,9.81) (11.5,6.06) (15,5.04) (15.5,4.788) (20.5,3.32) (26,2.58) (27.5,2.33) (30,2.12) (40,1.12) (50,0.85) (80,0.6972) (99,0.648)
};
\legend{Layers 1 to 5}

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Where are into your code `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}`?

Comment: Sorry forgot to add that. I edited it now :)

Comment: Into your code there are some errors: `Paragraph ended before \pgfflt@readlowlevelfloat was complete. [] Package PGF Math Error: Sorry, an internal routine of the floating point unit got an ill-formatted floating point number '0.0'. The unreadable part was near '0.0'.. [\end{axis}]`

Comment: @user157109 I don't understand what you want, but I guess that the option `line join = round` or the option `smooth` do what you want. Also, there's something wrong with the data point `(27,5,2.33)`, which is causing the error Sebastiano mentioned.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik Hi, peraphs increasing the number of the points with `samples=` is it possible to have a curve?

Comment: @Sebastiano this is a point plot, there are no samples to increase. `smooth` might help. But not much

Comment: @Sebastiano I don't know for sure, I'm not an expert here. But I think that the `samples` option is valid when you have an analytical function, not a discrete data set.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik it does not give an error but also does not change anything. A smooth curve to the points would be a fitting of some sorts which isn't really in the realm of pgfplots (it can do some, just not sure if this kind of data set is suited for it).

Comment: @daleif Neat, I didn't even know it could do curve fitting :) I imagined that, but wasn't sure. Thanks!

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik I want to create a curve in a coordinate system using data points. As can be seen in the image, lines are drawn between the data points, creating pointy connection points. I want to round them, but haven't found a way to do it. Is there otherwise an easier way of drawing a curve than the method Im using?

WHere should i put the "smooth" in my code? I tried "Line join=round" but it didnt make any difference.

Comment: I would suggest you to replot your curve in Ti*k*Z and use the `samples=200` method – it would be much easier …

Comment: @user157109 Beware that neither of these options will work a miracle. If you want a real continuous and smooth curve you will need some kind of curve fitting which, as daleif said, is not `pgfplots`' aim. The `line join = round` option will remove the sharp connection between two lines (this will be most noticeable at the peak of the plot). The `smooth` option will try to remove discontinuities in the curve, which can work to some extent. Either of these can be added as an option for `axis` (`\begin{axis}[smooth, ...]`) or for `\addplot` (`\addplot[smooth, ...]`).

Comment: The "smooth" option worked perfectly, thank you very much! :D

Comment: You could also add `tension=0.3`

Comment: `smooth` works fine in some cases, but there are also cases where it can cause overshoots and ruin the plot. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/371245/how-to-create-a-ricker-wavelet-in-tikz/371248#371248 for one example.

Answer (score 2):

As daleif said PGFPlots can't do much about the data you give it to plot. If it was an analytical (and smooth) function you could simply increase the number of samples and the plot would look smoother. With a discrete dataset there is not much that can be done; any graphing software won't do much more than connecting the dots.

PGFPlots however offers you some work-arounds to smoothen your plot without giving it more data.

Here's your original picture (with a few spy lenses):

> [image]

If I add the `smooth` option PGFPlots will, instead of a straight line, try to join your points with a smooth line. Smooth meaning that the tangent to the line is the same to the left and to the right of the point. This can make some weird output if the data points are too close and can't be drawn with a smooth line without overshooting. Your plot with `smooth`:

> [image]

The peak of the plot looks OK, but the second spy lens highlights a slight overshoot. That happened because the data points are too close and the tangent of the line changes too drastically between them.

The `smooth` option has a default “tension” for the line, which does more or less as the name says: the tension at the data points, which will say how much of the line will be smoothed. As Mr. marmot suggested you can reduce that tension (the default is `0.5` to have a better looking curve (picture with `tension=0.3`):

> [image]

Unfortunately you can't go much further without changing the underlying data.

Here's the code I used for the pictures:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{spy}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[spy using outlines]
  \begin{axis}[
      xlabel={Hydration time (h)},
      ylabel={Hydration heat evolution rate (J/gh)},
      xmin=0, xmax=100,
      ymin=0, ymax=20,
      legend pos=north east,
      ymajorgrids=true,
      grid style=dashed,
    ]
    \addplot[
      color=blue,
      smooth,
      tension=0.3,
    ]
      coordinates
      {
        (0,0) (0.5,3.59) (1.5,8.65) (2.5,15.026)
        (3.5,18.63) (4,18.07) (4.5,15.91) (6.5,9.81)
        (11.5,6.06) (15,5.04) (15.5,4.788) (20.5,3.32)
        (26,2.58) (27.5,2.33) (30,2.12) (40,1.12)
        (50,0.85) (80,0.6972) (99,0.648)
      };
    \legend{Layers 1 to 5}
    \coordinate (peak) at (axis cs:3.5,18.63);
    \coordinate (midd) at (axis cs:15,5.04);
  \end{axis}
  \spy [circle, magnification = 4, size = 1.5cm, connect spies] on (peak) in node at ($(peak)+(1.2,-1)$);
  \spy [circle, magnification = 4, size = 1.5cm, connect spies] on (midd) in node at ($(midd)+(1.2, 1)$);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

---

#### Where to put `smooth` and `tension=0.3`?

PGFPlots runs on TeX, and one of TeX's features is scoping. This coping applies to PGFPlots as well. There are four places where you can put these options and they will have different scopes:

1. Somewhere in the preamble put `\tikzset{smooth,tension=0.3}`: this will affect all `tikzpicture`s from that point on; this has a global effect and will be used in any drawing you have (not really recommended).
2. As an option to `tikzpicture` (`\begin{tikzpicture}[smooth,tension=0.3]`): this will limit the scope of these instructions to the current `tikzpicture` and will affect any drawing inside it. Once the `tikzpicture` ends, the effect ends as well.
3. As an option to `axis` (`\begin{axis}[smooth,tension=0.3]`): same as above, but the effect will be limited to that axis.
4. As an option to `\addplot` (`\addplot[smooth,tension=0.3]`): the scope of the options will be limited to that plot only. Any other plot, even in the same axis, will have the default options. Since you want to smoothen this specific curve, this is the way to go, as the scope is exactly the one you want.