# Function curve not rendering correctly

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, graphs

For some reason, I cannot render the 2-parameter logistic item characteristic curve equation with the given parameters a = 13.67 and b = -1.58.

[image]

I use the given code.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    enlargelimits=false,
    xlabel={$\theta$},
    ylabel={probability},
    xmin=-7, xmax=7,
    ymin=-0.5, ymax=1.5,
    legend pos=north west,
    legend entries={test}
    ]
    \addlegendimage{gray}
]

\addplot [smooth, gray, domain=-10:10]{exp(13.67*(x+1.58))/(1 + exp(13.67*(x+1.58)))};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

And this is the output.

[image]

However, when I graph the same function on Desmos, it doesn't look as ugly...

[image]

The logistic functions isn't supposed to be above 1 or below 0. What am I doing wrong so that the output is so off on LaTeX?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try removing `smooth` and add `samples=200` or so...

Comment: @Rmano Thanks, that did it.

Answer (score 7):

Do not use `smooth`: it draws splines between points and in case of strong slope changes it can overshoot.

This is the curve without `smooth`, where you can see the steep derivative changes that fool the splines:

[image]

Just use more points, like `samples=200`.

[image]

You can also fine-tune it more, with for example:

```
\addplot [blue, domain=-10:10,
    samples at={-10,-9.5,...,-2.5,   % -10 ...-2.5 every 0.5
                -2.45,-2.4,...,-0.5, % -2.45 ... -0.5 every 0.05
                0,0.5,...,10},       % 0 ... 10 every 0.5
    ]{exp(13.67*(x+1.58))/(1 + exp(13.67*(x+1.58)))};
```

[image]

Full MWE:

```latex
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{pgfplots}\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    enlargelimits=false,
    xlabel={$\theta$},
    ylabel={probability},
    xmin=-7, xmax=7,
    ymin=-0.5, ymax=1.5,
    legend pos=north west,
    legend entries={test},
    grid
    ]
    \addlegendimage{gray}
]

\addplot [blue, domain=-10:10,
    samples at={-10,-9.5,...,-2.5,   % -10 ...-2.5 every 0.5
                -2.45,-2.4,...,-0.5, % -2.45 ... -0.5 every 0.05
                0,0.5,...,10},       % 0 ... 10 every 0.5
    ]{exp(13.67*(x+1.58))/(1 + exp(13.67*(x+1.58)))};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

I'm sure it's a duplicate, but I can't found it now... (now it's less duplicate ;-))

Comment: Quite similar to https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/371245/how-to-create-a-ricker-wavelet-in-tikz/371248#371248 I suppose.

Comment: Then I didn't have to vote on your answer ahahaha.

Answer (score 3):

I would say that is a common "problem"/question. And that mostly is, because people often don't know at which points the given function is evaluated. That means in which interval with how many points. And that is caused by directly plotting the function without the markers. So my advice is: Don't turn off the markers until you are close to the result you want to achieve! The long form of the default is `\addplot+ [domain=-5:5,samples=25] {<f(x)>};` where `f(x)` is the function to plot. (The option `smooth` should be self-explanatory.)

So Rmano is totally right in [his answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/600354/95441) that `smooth` is responsible for the strange look of the curve. But the *real* source of the problem is the user. If you would just have plotted the curve *with* markers, then I think you would have come to the real source of the problem yourself. One can guess it also from Rmano's first image (i.e. just removing `smooth`).

So also having a `domain` that is larger than the axis limits results in only *one* point that is not at the lower or upper (y) limit of the function ...

If you have created the Desmos plot after the PGFPlots plot, latest then you should have noticed that it would be totally sufficient to plot the graph within the xlimits `-2.5` to `-0.5`, right? That would be the simplest and best solution if there isn't a good reason to have the xlimits of `-7` and `7`.

If you really should need the big xlimits, then you can of course simply increase `samples` to a number that the function looks smooth (enough). But you could also think a minute about the function and its behavior to find a another simple solution for the problem without increasing (drastically) the number of `samples`.

What do you think about my solution (still using the default number of `samples`)?

```
% used PGFPlots v1.18.1
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    % declare variables/functions
    declare function={
        % axis limits
        xmin=-7;
        xmax=7;
        % ---------------------------------------------------------------------
        % Logistic function
        L(\x,\b,\a) = exp(\a*(\x+\b))/(1 + exp(\a*(\x+\b)));
        % create simplified functions when `a` and `b` are known/fix
        a = 13.67;
        b = 1.58;
        myL(\x) = L(\x,b,a);
        % ---------------------------------------------------------------------
        %%% use the knowledge we have from the function
        % we "know" (from a/the plot) that the function is point symmetric around `b`
        % and by testing that 10 times the inverse of `a` is enough to reach the lower and upper y bounds
        DeltaX = 10/a;
        % so it is enough to evaluate the function within that limits
        lb = -b - DeltaX;
        ub = -b + DeltaX;
        % and if it should really be necessary to have that large xrange,
        % it is enough to draw horizontal lines from that calculation limits
        % to the axis limits
        DeltaToXMax = xmax - ub;
        DeltaToXMin = xmin - lb;
    },
]
    \begin{axis}[
        xlabel={$\theta$},
        ylabel={probability},
        xmin=xmin,  % <-- (use defined variable)
        xmax=xmax,  % <-- (use defined variable)
        ymin=-0.1,
        ymax=1.1,
        smooth,
        clip=false, % <-- just for debugging
    ]

        % old solution with above defined function
        % (so you see that in both cases the same function is used)
        % (added `+` after `\addplot` so you can see the points where the
        %  function is evaluated and thus you know where the error is coming from)
        \addplot+ [domain=-10:10] {myL(x)};

        % new solution
        % evaluate the function within the defined limits ...
        \addplot+ [domain=lb:ub,mark=o] {myL(x)}
            % ... and extend the line (from the last calculated point at `ub`) to `xmax`.
            -- ++(axis direction cs:DeltaToXMax,0)
            % Also draw the line (from the first calculated point at `lb`) to `xmin`
            % for which we first have to jump to the point at `lb` again
            (axis cs:lb,{myL(lb)}) -- ++(axis direction cs:DeltaToXMin,0)
        ;

    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result to above code]